# Handling tables in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm learning Bootstrap 3 so I'm not perfectly proficient in it yet.

In my web app, I have large tables with many columns. Is there a technique to make them mobile friendly using Bootstrap 3?

I can think of two ways I can approach this but not sure on how to handle it in Bootstrap 3.

First approach is to get the table use only the available space which means columns will get squeezed.

The second approach would be to "not display" certain columns to make space for more important columns.

I think both approaches would be useful depending on the situation. I'd appreciate some guidance on how to implement these approaches.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Scroll to the Responsive Tables section.